# PHP Zend 2 issue finding template

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm picking up php after a few years away and starting with Zend2 skeleton template tutorials.

I'm getting this error

Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "fun-ex/fun-ex/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file

Which is right there is no such directory as fun-ex/fun-ex it should be the directory view/funex/index/ but I can't understand why I did not set fun-ex/fun-ex anywhere in the code.

I'm still pretty new to working in the backend so if theres a resource to some fundamental concept I'm overlooking a point in the rightdirection would be greatly apperciated.Cheers

```
 array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'FunEx\Controller\FunEx',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'funex' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'FunEx\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'FunEx',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'FunEx\Controller\FunEx' => 'FunEx\Controller\FunExController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'funex/index/index'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/funex/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the view manager will look for view files at `<modulename>/<controller>/<action>`. This is the `template_path_stack` line in your config. The names are converted to lower case, and camel-cased letters get dashes, so that's why `FunEx` becomes `fun-ex`.

If your view is at `/module/FunEx/view/funex/index/index.phtml` as indicated by your comment, the simplest fix would be for you to rename the folders to match what it's looking for. In this case `/module/FunEx/view/fun-ex/fun-ex/index.phtml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim. Now I understand that the camel casing is what creates the dash I'm now even more sure it's something in the module.config as the view directory is not camel cased.

I don't really want to just change the directory name without understanding how it works.

Comment: Which part is unclear? The view manager will look for `<modulename>/<controller>/<action>` within each path in the template path stack. Your module name is `FunEx`, which becomes `fun-ex`, as is the controller, so it's looking for `fun-ex/fun-ex/index` within `/module/FunEx/view`, which is the path your module config added to the template path stack.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is not the explanation I'm looking for.

Comment: I've explained what's causing the error in your question, and how to fix it. You'll need to give us more information about exactly what you're trying to achieve if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

the error indicates that you have no `index.phtml` file in your `view` folder. located at
(if your module is named `FunEx`)

`/module/FunEx/view/funex/index/index.phtml`

Comment: thats what I don't get that file absolutely does exist it's 'module' not 'modules' directory could that be it?

Comment: have you set the correct permissions to the folder location for the running php user? i edited my answer the module folder in zf2 is called ``module`` not ``modules``

Comment: Should be fine I'm using xampp on osx, the default application renders fine, so I must have something wrong in the settings, so far I've tried renaming every instance of 'index' in the module to index000 just to see if I can get a different path in the error, no dice.

Comment: The only `index` in the error is the last part of the template path. This comes the name of the action being rendered. If you want to see the error change, modify both the action name in your route and the name of the equivalent `indexAction()` method in your controller.